# EJECUTAR JAVASCRIPT CUANDO SELECCIONE UN VALOR DEL <SELECT>

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Tengo un < Select > en el cual tengo listado unos vehículos.
En mi BD tengo información del kilometraje de cada vehículo por mes y cuanto debería de ser su consumo.

Lo que deseo hacer es:

- Cuando seleccione un vehículo se actualicen los input text según los datos que se obtengan de la base de datos, es decir si selecciono "VOLVO" que en el primer input text me aparezca el valor de KM inicial que hizo el vehiculo, en el segundo input text me aparezca el KM actual del vehículo y en el < span > me aparezca el consumo que debería de hacer el bus.
- Estaba pensando hacer un código javascript para poder hacer esto, pero no se me ocurre nada, estoy nublado de ideas :(

```html
<form>
  <table>
    <tr><td>
      <select>
        <option disabled selected>Selecciona un vehiculo</option>
        <option value="1">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="2">Volvo</option>
        <option value="3">Toyota</option>
      </select>
    <td></tr>
    <tr><td>KM 1er dia del mes:► <input type="text" name="combustible_t2a" readonly><td></tr>
    <tr><td>KM actual:► <input type="text" name="combustible_t2b" readonly><td></tr>
    <tr><td>Consumo:► <span id="consumo_movilidad"><span><td></tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

**Tengo 2 Tablas relacionadas:**

Vehículos
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Servicios
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: implementa el evento `onChange` de tu select y dentro de este deberías realizar las llamadas a tu BD para obtener la información que necesitas

Comment: Me podrías realizar un ejemplo por favor, lo agradecería demasiado

Answer (score 1):

Usnado solo javascript puedes agregar una funcion al `onchange` en la etiqueta `<select>` y recibir el valor actual pasando como parametro `this` y cambiar el valor de los input usando sus id. Te dejo un pequeño ejemplo. Dentro de la variable `resp` en la funcion `success` estan los datos que te entrego tu script php.

```
 <table>
    <tr><td>
      <select onchange="actualizar(this)">
        <option disabled selected>Selecciona un vehiculo</option>
        <option value="1">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="2">Volvo</option>
        <option value="3">Toyota</option>
      </select>
    <td></tr>
    <tr><td>Objeto seleccionado:► <input id="objetoval" type="text" name="objetoval" readonly><td></tr> 
    <tr><td>KM 1er dia del mes:► <input type="text" name="combustible_t2a" readonly><td></tr>
    <tr><td>KM actual:► <input type="text" name="combustible_t2b" readonly><td></tr>
    <tr><td>Consumo:► <span id="consumo_movilidad"><span><td></tr>
  </table>
</form>
<script>
    function actualizar(opcion){
        console.log("Actualizando datos",opcion.value);
        document.getElementById("objetoval").value=opcion.value;
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/script.php',
            data: {id:opcion.value}
          success: function(resp) {
            //Aqui cambias el valor de tus inputs
          }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: como podria ejecutrar un query php en js para obtener los datos de mi BD?

Comment: Te agregue un ejemplo con el metodo POST ya que te dejaron otro ejemplo con GET

Comment: Me sale error actualizar no está definido,

Comment: Tengo otra consulta, cuando seleccione un elemento del select quiero que se ejecute un SELECT * FROM a mi BD y obtener datos que serán impresos en los 2 input y en el span que están en mi formulario.

Comment: Esas funciones las debes tener en el archivo script.php y retornar un json por ejemplo que estara en la variable resp. Luego ya puedes acceder a los datos como si fuera un objeto: resp.nombre

Comment: Soy nuevo en este tema, me podrías explicar en un ejemplo por favor 

Comment: Aqui ya tienes un ejemplo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383631/json-encode-mysql-results

Comment: Se me está haciendo un quilombo la cabeza, con lo del JSON y cómo utilizarlo en mi form

Answer (score 1):

para lo que requieres es necesario JavaScript, aqui tienes un pequeño ejemplo que realize con Jquery, espero te sirva de algo

```
//Coloca aqui el id de tu select, esta función te detecta cuando haces un cambio en tu selección
$("#marca").change(function () {
        // aqui vuelve a colocar el id de tu select, pero en esta ocación detectamos el valor que tiene el mismo
        $("#marca option:selected").each(function () {
            // luego guardas el valor en una variable
            id_mar = $(this).val();
            //luego envias el valor a tu archivo donde armaras tu consulta a la base de datos 
            $.get("controlador/selectModelo2.php", { id_marca: id_mar }, function(data){
                aqui colocas el id del input donde quieres mostrar la respuesta
                $("#modelo").html(data);

            });            
        });
    });
```

luego podrias guiarte de este ejemplo para recibir el id

Codigo = $ver[1];

}


// finalmente envias el objeto $datos en un json 
echo json_encode($datos);
?>

Comment: tendrias que obviamente agregarle un id a tu select: <select id="marca">, para que puedas hacer referencia a este en el javascript

Comment: Tengo otra consulta, cuando seleccione un elemento del select quiero que se ejecute un SELECT * FROM a mi BD y obtener datos que serán impresos en los 2 input y en el span que están en mi formulario.